# what are the discussion board alternatives in SharePoint

Tags: 2016, discussion-board

please let me know if there are any alternatives for discussion board in sharepoint!

what's the type of customization can be achieved in the current boring discussion board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In SharePoint Server**, the **NewsFeed** is a great discussion collaboration option. In NewsFeed, you can use **@** to mention users and to add **#** hashtag like twitter style.

[image]

Check the main difference between NewsFeed and Discussion board at

- [What is the difference between Discussion board and newsfeed ? notifications can be done fo both?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214682/what-is-the-difference-between-discussion-board-and-newsfeed-notifications-can?rq=1)
- [Newsfeed or Discussion Board?](https://sharepointmaven.com/newsfeed-or-discussion-board/)

---

**In case,** you have Office 365 subscription, you can use [Yammer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/get-started-with-yammer/admin-key-concepts) or team news, communication site as social collaboration options,

---

Also, there are 3rd party solutions for discussion board like [Discussion Board Plus](https://bamboosolutions.com/discussion-board-plus/), check also [Enhanced SharePoint discussion forum/Q&A](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/enhanced-sharepoint-discussion-forum-qa)

Comment: thanks,what's the type of customization can be achieved in the current boring discussion board?

Comment: In my opinion, NOTHING, you can't edit view from GUI, you will need to use SharePoint Designer to do it, a bit CSS customization can be achieved!!

Comment: check also https://anothersharepointblog.com/modify-the-view-of-sharepoint-discussion-board and http://zeddylabs.com/2013/07/the-ultimate-sharepoint-discussion-board-customization/

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you can @-tag 3 people only.